# Is there a state-of-the-art deep learning paper that uses center point regression instead of bounding box regression, for object tracking?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, bounding-box, siamese-neural-network, object-tracking

Almost all deep learning based object tracking methods perform bounding box regression. Siamese-based networks which are very popular for object tracking also perform bounding box regression most of the time, although SiamFC type exceptions exist. And some other networks use a detection + tracking mechanism using the center points of the objects, however, what I am looking for is whether any Siamese based networks that predict the center of the object rather than the bounding box exist. I searched the literature but couldn't find any, I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some bounding box models like yolo has output of 4 channels: hight-center, width-center,hight-size, width. and with they constract the bounding box, so you can modify those models to use only the first 2 channels.